# Will placing a battery in water short circuit it? (Performing electrolysis)

Tags: electricity, short-circuits

I've learned about electrolysis and wanted to try it out but i've popped a couple of batteries by short-circuiting them before messing around with embedded programming so I was curious as I see on youtube videos people just placing both terminals in the water (usually a 9 volt with paper clips)

If it didn't harm the battery I was going to try dip my 10W solar panel terminals in and collect the hydrogen gas.

Complete beginner in everything psychics by the way so if you could, can you explain it to I as a nooby whether or not I will ruin my battery/solar panel.

Comment: You probably won't ruin the panel itself, but you may ruin the terminals. Remember that "electrolysis" is really "chemistry," and there may be chemical reactions between the electrodes (i.e. the terminals) and the electrolyte which occur *because* of the electrical voltage you are applying. That is why commercial electrolysis often uses electrodes made from unreactive materials like platinum, rather than "some random mixture of tin or nickel-plated brass, copper, solder, etc" that the terminals of your panel may be made from.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a short-circuit is that enough current is generated to cause overheating in some part of the circuit.
If you put a paperclip across the terminals of a battery, the element that overheats is usually the battery.

You can measure how much current this is by including an [ammeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter) in your battery-water circuit. If necessary, you can add some [resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor) to the circuit to limit the current.
You can get a multimeter, which includes an ammeter, from any hardware store for \$10-\$20.

[One brand of nine-volt battery](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/522.pdf) will run for about a half-hour at 500 milliamps, or for about a day at 25 milliamps.

Comment: Op might want to consider adding a fuse to his circuit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_cutoff